# Vuejs : SSR not working

Tags: vuejs2, server-side-rendering

I am using the hackernews Vuejs as a template. When I am using AsyncData in components it's not working

**AsyncData**

```
asyncData({ store }) {
    return store.dispatch('LOCATIONS');
},
```

**Action**

```
LOCATIONS: ({ commit, state }) => {
    return state.locationList.length ? Promise.resolve(state.locationList) : axios.get('http://localhost:3000/api/Locations').then(({ data }) => commit('SET_LOCATIONS', data))
}
```

When I call the same action from created() or beforeMounted() etc. It is working and the state is getting updated but when using as asyncData the API is not even getting called.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the answer from [nuxtjs.org](https://nuxtjs.org/faq/async-data-components/):

> Because components do not have an asyncData method, you cannot
>   directly fetch async data server side within a component. In order to
>   get around there limitation you have two basic options:
>
> Make the API call in the mounted() hook and set data properties when
>   loaded. Downside: Won't work for server side rendering. Make the API
>   call in the asyncData() or fetch() methods of the page component and
>   pass the data as props to the sub components. Server rendering will
>   work fine. Downside: the asyncData() or fetch() of the page might be
>   less readable because it's loading the data for other components